# How to retrieve entries from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a application, that is used to manage assistant jobs. Therefore, the model is composed of 3 models: Person, Course, Application (typical many-to-many relation).
My `models.py` looks as follow:

```
class Person(AbstractUser):
  ...

class Course(models.Model):
  year = models.charField(max_length=9)
  term = ...

class Applications(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="applicant")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Pending')
```

In the context of a form, I need to retrieve all the courses a person has been hired in order to populate a dropdown list.

It is easy to get all the applications of the currently logged in user having the status 'Hired':

```
Applications.objects.filter(applicant=user, status="Hired")
```

but I can't get a a queryset of all the related courses:

```
Applications.objects.filter(applicant=user, status="Hired").course_set
```

returns me an:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'course_set'

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships), this attribute should exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse accessor `course_set` is available on an *instance* of `Applications` model, not on the queryset (which `Applications.objects.filter` returns).

For example, if you have an `Applications` instance named `application`, you can do:

```
application.course_set.all()
```

to get all the instances of `Course` that are related to `application`.

---

If you want to get the related `Course` instances from filtered `Applicaitons`:

```
Applications.objects.filter(
    applicant=user, status="Hired"
).values_list(
    'course', flat=True
).distinct()
```

This will return the primary keys of related `Course` instances.

Comment: so I guess I should loop over the Applications queryset to build a list of courses. correct?

Comment: @E.Jaep What's your eventual goal?

Comment: In the ModelForm I am giving the user, I want to narrow down a list of courses to the courses where the person is hired. Not the full list of courses.

Typically, I should end up in the initialization of the form to something like `self.fields['class_teaching_course'].queryset=user_courses`

Comment: @E.Jaep `Applications.objects.filter(applicant=user, status="Hired").values_list('course', flat=True).distinct()`

Comment: @heermayl if you put your latest comment as answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @E.Jaep No problem. Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use _set to access it.

Try with the docs first, to get the idea. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/